# No air-conditioning

Tags: noise, hvac, gmc, tracker

If the AC was leaking and someone unhooked the AC unit, would that be causing the belt to squeak now?

If so, what would you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What do you mean by leaking and unhooked. In order for us to answer much greater detail must Be given

Comment: Definitely give more info, not enough detail to give a reasonable answer.

Comment: @Peggy  How did you unhook the AC?  Did you remove a fuse? Discharge the lines?  Take out the compressor?  Also, are you sure it's the belt squeaking, or are you simply hearing a squeaking noise and are wondering if it might be the belt?

Comment: This seems to work:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8RE8p_m8bA